# How to hide element blocking click? ElementClickInterceptedException - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation, click, hide

I am getting error ElementClickInterceptedException when Selenium tries to click a specific element on the page. This element is just a popup and I would like to simply ***hide*** it. I would like to hide it because this element changes it's class name and it's position in the DOM from time to time so using the class name would only work for so long.

My code is a simple WebDriverWait & click like any other:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 999).until(                          
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__layout"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/button'))).click()
```

The error I am getting is:

```
 File "C:\Users\lmdel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 81, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\lmdel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 710, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\lmdel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 425, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\lmdel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button type="button" class="button button_lg button_blue button_center" data-v-7e25d36a="" data-v-5a795cf4="">...</button> is not clickable at point (1137, 32). Other element would receive the click: <div data-v-1d38c9d6="" class="modal-wrapper" style="z-index: 1;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.114)
```

Comment: `<div data-v-1d38c9d6="" class="modal-wrapper" style="z-index: 1;">...</div>` which element is this?

Comment: elem=WebDriverWait(self.driver, 999).until(                          
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__layout"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/button'))) you could use javascript to invoke click on that element instead driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click", elem)

Comment: @undetected Selenium - That is the element that is blocking the click. How do I dynamically retrieve the element like Selenium's error handler did? 

For example, imagine the element was `<div data-x-4d7byd8="" class="modal-wrapper2" style="z-index: 1;">Close</div>` the next time I opened the page. How would I get this element even though the element that is blocking the click has changed?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium (It didnt let me edit my comment)